# Is it still necessary/useful to execute \robustify\(?

Tags: math-mode, robust-commands, fixltx2e

I know that `etoolbox` provides a `robustify` command and I've been executing `\robustify\(` in my headers forever now. But, answers like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4747/2743) also suggest loading fix `fixltx2e` to make it robust.

However, CTAN now says that package does nothing but produce a warning and when I go through the logs describing changes to latex the entry for 2019-10-01 says that many previously fragile commands have been made robust but doesn't mention `\(` and `\)` explicitly.

So are `\(` and `\)` now defined to be robust?

Comment: In addition to moewe's answer, `latex '\ShowCommand\( \stop'` tells you that the command is robust: `> \(=robust macro: ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With an up-to-date LaTeX `\show\(` produces

```
> \(=macro:
->\x@protect \(\protect \(  .
l.10 \show\(
```

which looks very robust.

And indeed a look at [`source2e`, §E.1.2, p. 494 in version 2020-10-01PL4](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) shows that since `2015/01/01` we have had

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\({%
  \relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\){%
  \relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}%
```

[image: \IncludeInRelease{2015/01/01}{(}{Make ( robust}% followed by the new robust definition quoted above. Below that the fragile definition.]

In [`ltnews`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews.pdf) 22 from January 2015 we find that all fixes from `fixltx2e` are now enabled by default in the LaTeX kernel, so in particular the kernel now defines `\(` and `\)` as robust commands. In issue 26 from January 2017 of `ltnews` we find that all changes from `fixltx2e` that were added to the kernel in LaTeX version `2015-01-01` are guarded by `\IncludeInRelease{2015/01/01}`, so can be rolled back with `latexrelease`.

Hence, if you want to test with the old fragile behaviour, you can roll back your LaTeX version with `latexrelease` to a date before `2015/01/01`, e.g.

```
\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\(x\)}
\end{document}
```